# R read.table long string

Tags: r, read.table

I have a log file (txt) with separations of tab:

```
T<=>31158[=]P<=>iexplore.exe[=]I<=>1096[=]U<=>http://tieba.baidu.com/p/1576129401[=]A<=>3504a4[=]B<=>540532[=]V<=>8.00.6001.18702   34682   77  2012-05-07_07-52-43
T<=>31200[=]P<=>iexplore.exe[=]I<=>1096[=]U<=>javascript:var c=rich_postor._getData();c.content=&#25105;&#29233;&#20320;;for(var i=1;i<=999;i++){PostHandler.post(rich_postor._option.url,c,function(I){rich_postor.showAddResult(I)},function(I){});};void 0[=]A<=>3504a4[=]B<=>540532[=]V<=>8.00.6001.18702   34682   77  2012-05-07_07-52-43
T<=>31212[=]P<=>iexplore.exe[=]I<=>1096[=]U<=>http://tieba.baidu.com/p/1576129401   34682   77  2012-05-07_07-52-43
```

When I imported this file, it returned error:

```
df <- read.table("2012-05-07.txt", sep="\t", quote="", stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
line 2 did not have 4 elements
```

if I added the arg 'fill= TRUE', no error popped but the dataset was wrong:

```
df <- read.table("2012-05-07.txt", sep="\t", fill= TRUE, quote="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df[2, ]
V1
T<=>31200[=]P<=>iexplore.exe[=]I<=>1096[=]U<=>javascript:var c=rich_postor._getData();c.content=&
  V2 V3 V4
```

The first cell should be

```
T<=>31200[=]P<=>iexplore.exe[=]I<=>1096[=]U<=>javascript:var c=rich_postor._getData();c.content=&#25105;&#29233;&#20320;;for(var i=1;i<=999;i++){PostHandler.post(rich_postor._option.url,c,function(I){rich_postor.showAddResult(I)},function(I){});};void 0[=]A<=>3504a4[=]B<=>540532[=]V<=>8.00.6001.18702
```

but it is

```
T<=>31200[=]P<=>iexplore.exe[=]I<=>1096[=]U<=>javascript:var c=rich_postor._getData();c.content=&
```

it breaks at `#`, it seems that the string `"&#25105;&#29233;&#20320;"` is the Chinese words for 'I love you'. Could anyone tell me how to get all the string in one cell? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `#` is the default for the `comment.char`. Change this.

Comment: @Roland thanks! Just learned another argument.

Answer (score 0):

Set the argument `comment.char` empty:

```
read.table("file.txt", header= TRUE, quote= "", sep="\t", comment.char= "", stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
```